# Integral involving trigonometry/algebraic manipulation

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Given that $\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=A$ and that $\int_0^1 x^{2π-1}f(x^π)dx=1$, it follows that $\cos A=$ ?

I don't know how to approach this problem. I think that solving for $f(x^π)$ should be where to start but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution $y=x^{\pi}$ in the second integral gives $\int_0^{1} yf(y)dy=\pi$. Hnce $A=\pi$ and $\cos A=-1$.

[ $x=y^{1/\pi}$ gives $dx=\frac  1 {\pi} y^{1/\pi -1} dy$. Hence $\int_0^{1}x^{2\pi-1} f(x^{\pi}) dx=\int_0^{1}y^{2-1/\pi}f(y)\frac  1 {\pi} y^{1/\pi-1} dy=\frac 1 {\pi}\int_0^{1} yf(y)dt$].

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=A$$ $$\int_0^1 x^{2π-1}f(x^π)dx=1$$

---

$$\int_0^1 x^{2π-1}f(x^π)dx=1$$

Let $t=x^{\pi} \implies dx=dt \cdot \frac{x^{1-\pi}}{\pi}$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{t^2}{x}f(t) x^{1-\pi} dt =\pi$$

$$\int_0^1 tf(t)dt=\pi$$
$$\implies \boxed{A=\pi}$$